# Is Goenka's "Freeflow of sensations" the same as pīti?

Tags: vipassana, meditation-effects, sn-goenka

In the S.N. Goenka vipassana tradition the meditator tries to reach a 'freeflow' of sensations on and in the body. Is this 'freeflow' comparable with Pīti?

Comment: Not familiar with Goenka but is this "freeflow" a generally positive feeling?
Also in the case of the "freeflow" in the Goenka tradition is this freeflow to be eventually let go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Free flow is loosely used for Piti. Initially it is subtle vibrations which you feel. As you practice this spreads to your body. These vibrations are pleasant.

Comment: Would you be so kind to dig a bit deeper. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The free flow is when the whole body dissolves into subtle vibrations, and you reach the stage of *bhanga*, total dissolution. It causes *pīti* (pleasant sensation, rapture, bliss) and if not careful you can develop attachment to it.